# Strange cross in Gaussian distribution image (python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, gaussian

EDIT: Towards the bottom is a shorter version, where the problem is, so there's less of a wall of code.

I'm not exactly sure what my problem is here, so I don't think my previous search for an answer would have been very effective. Apologies if this has been covered before.

I am attempting to create an image of Gaussian distributed random data, with a mean and standard deviation provided in the code. The axes are spatial scales, supposed to be an astronomical sources motion from its original position, due to the effects of the Earths atmosphere. So if a source appears to move 2 units left and one down from its original position, it will be encoded into the image I am producing, in the pixel 2 left of the central pixel, and one below it. If 10 sources moved in this way, then that pixel would have a value of 10.

My output image is almost correct, but for a strange cross shape about the central pixel. For some reason, there seems to be a large number of sources that have not moved in either the x or y directions, which should not be. The output image should look like a Gaussian distribution.

Does anyone see anything in my code that could be causing this? I have to admit, I'm not entirely sure how the quad() function works, but I also do not see how this could be affecting it, as it is simply used to get the number of sources that should be visible in any observation for a given flux range.

The other possibility is that because I am truncating the motion information, that is causing this artificial inflation for small motion?

Thank you for any help :)

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import copy
import random
from scipy.integrate import quad
import time
from scipy.stats import linregress

start_time = time.clock()

steradians_of_obs = 7.5
threshold_flux_Jy = 1

FoV = 30
Alt = 300
ion_patch = 2*Alt*np.tan(FoV*np.pi/360) # determine the size of the ionospheric patch being observed

image_size_x = int(ion_patch) # Determine the shape of the image, based on the size of the
image_size_y = int(ion_patch) # ionospheric patch being observed. 1km => 1pixel
              # Will be corrected for later

repeat_obs = 1

max_spatial_freq_x = 3*10**8/image_size_y # Assuming the spatial size and wavelength work like
max_spatial_freq_y = 3*10**8/image_size_x # frequency and wavelength of light
                  # To be fixed up later

#  ____  __  __  _  _  ___  ____  ____  _____  _  _  ___ 
# ( ___)(  )(  )( \( )/ __)(_  _)(_  _)(  _  )( \( )/ __)
#  )__)  )(__)(  )  (( (__   )(   _)(_  )(_)(  )  ( \__ \
# (__)  (______)(_)\_)\___) (__) (____)(_____)(_)\_)(___/

def n_S(S):
# Import: I'm not sure how this import works...???
# Export: The equation that is to be integrated: 3600xS^-1.78
    return 3600*S**(-1.78)

def source_num(sr,flux):
# Imports: The steradians on the sky the observation covered
#      The threshold flux for the observation
# Exports: The number of sources within the observation
# Function:
#      Finds the integral from the thrshold flux to 1Jy of n(S) wrt S
#      to get the number of sources per steradian
#      Multiplies this by the number of steradians to get the total source count
    ans, err = quad(n_S,flux,1000)
    sources = ans*sr
    return sources

def source_count(rand_motion): 
# Imports: list of random motions for each individual observation, of length 
#      equal to the number of sources determined by the threshold flux
# Exports: an array of sources in positions from center, relating to their motion
# Function:
#     Sets up an array of dimensions of original image
#     makes sure array is of odd lengths on all sides
#     if even on at least one side, makes even sides odd by removing a row/column
#     Places a count of sources that have moved an amount given by their 
#     position from centre of array
#     ie.   if rand_motion[0] = (10.415209461822418, 8.29546673687272)
#       then the element image[10,8] has its value increased by 1
#       as the array element values are being truncated
    x_len = image_size_x
    y_len = image_size_y
    image = np.zeros((y_len,x_len),dtype='float64')
    if y_len%2 == 0:
        y_len-=1
    if x_len%2 == 0:
        x_len-=1
    image = image[0:y_len,0:x_len]
    for src_num in range(len(rand_motion)):
        y_dir = int(rand_motion[src_num][0])
        x_dir = int(rand_motion[src_num][1])
        image[y_dir+y_len/2,x_dir+x_len/2] += 1
    return image

#  ___  ____  __  __  __  __  __      __   ____  ____  ____     ____    __   ____   __
# / __)(_  _)(  \/  )(  )(  )(  )    /__\ (_  _)( ___)(  _ \   (  _ \  /__\ (_  _) /__\
# \__ \ _)(_  )    (  )(__)(  )(__  /(__)\  )(   )__)  )(_) )   )(_) )/(__)\  )(  /(__)\
# (___/(____)(_/\/\_)(______)(____)(__)(__)(__) (____)(____/   (____/(__)(__)(__)(__)(__)

number_of_sources = source_num(steradians_of_obs, threshold_flux_Jy)
# from the input values of the size of the observation and the minimum flux being detected, work out how many sources are going to be in the field

# set up parameters
test_image = []
fshift_sim_all = []
source_count_array_all = []
power_spectrum_sim_all = []
FTxSQRT_PS_all = []
ift_all = []
powerspec_fin_all = []
collapsed_PS_all = []
count_kw_all = []
all_rand_motion = []
ift_shift_all = []

for count in range(repeat_obs): # for every observation taken
            # get random motion information
    rand_motion = []
    mean = 10 # set the average for the random motion
    st_dev = 10 # set the standard deviation of the random motion
    for src_num in range(int(number_of_sources)): # for every source detected
        x_motion = random.gauss(mean,st_dev) # determine a random motion along x
        y_motion = random.gauss(mean,st_dev) # determine a random motion along y
        rand_motion.append((y_motion,x_motion)) # add motion of source to list

#rand_motion_py = []
#for i in range(len(rand_motion)):
#   rand_motion_py.append(np.sqrt(rand_motion[i][0]**2+rand_motion[i][1]**2))

#plt.plot(rand_motion_py,'.')
#plt.show()

    all_rand_motion.append(rand_motion) # the list of random motion for each observation
                    # currently only 1 observation, will increase later
    source_count_array = source_count(all_rand_motion[count]) 
    # place number of sources that have moved a certain amount in a pixel the distance of 
    # that motion away from the central pixel

plt.imshow(source_count_array)
plt.show()
# This comes out with a strange cross shape around the central pixel, 
# if the sources themselves are close enough to that area.
# If the mean of motion is significantly far away from the central pixel, 
# and the st dev is small, the stange cross shape does not appear.
# For some reason the amplitude of pixels along the x and y axes, 
# around and near the central point are being artificaillay amplified.
```

EDIT: I've worked out the problem is in the function source_count. I'm passing it a list ((y0,x0),(y1,x1),...) of the randomly Gaussian generated positions of numerous sources, and it is supposed to be generating an image (array) of these sources in a position that relates to their motion. This is going to have to truncate the motions of the sources, as I am binning them, but I don't understand why I would be getting the cross.

```
def source_count(rand_motion): 
# Imports: list of random motions for each individual observation, of length 
#      equal to the number of sources determined by the threshold flux
# Exports: an array of sources in positions relating to their motion
# Function:
#     Sets up an array of dimensions of original image
#     makes sure array is of odd lengths on all sides
#     if even on at least one side, makes even sides odd by removing a row/column
#     Places a count of sources that have moved an amount given by their 
#     position from centre of array
#     ie.   if rand_motion[0] = (10.415209461822418, 8.29546673687272)
#       then the element image[10,8] has its value increased by 1
#       as the array element values are being truncated
    x_len = image_size_x
    y_len = image_size_y
    image = np.zeros((y_len,x_len),dtype='float64')
    if y_len%2 == 0:
        y_len-=1
    if x_len%2 == 0:
        x_len-=1
    image = image[0:y_len,0:x_len]
    for source_num in range(len(rand_motion)):
        y_dir = int(rand_motion[source_num][0])
        x_dir = int(rand_motion[source_num][1])
        image[y_dir+y_len/2,x_dir+x_len/2] += 1
    return image
```

Comment: That's a wall of code to wade through and I haven't done so, but from your description it sounds suspiciously like some kind of truncation due to integer math. Make sure you specifiy floating point literals where you need precision and double-check any rounding.

Comment: Yes it is, I reduced it as much as I could, while still trying to explain what I was doing. I will have a look through and see if your suggestion helps. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found it!! I had y_dir and x_dir in the function source_count being made to be integers. Once I removed that, it worked perfectly.

I don't really understand why that works, as I thought the line

```
image[y_dir+y_len/2,x_dir+x_len/2] += 1
```

would also truncates in the same way? Actually, I thought I would get an error when I tried this.

I would like to know why this worked though, if anyone would like to explain it/send me to somewhere I can find out for myself :)